# ArrayBuffer и Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, c++, c

Подскажите пожалуйста ArrayBuffer в Javascript - это некий аналог void* в Си ?

```
let my_buff = new ArrayBuffer(10);

alert(my_buff [2]);              //Это не имеет смысла.

const view = new Uint8Array(my_buff);

view [0] = 55;
alert(view [0]);
```

.

```
std::string my_string = "Hello_World";


void* my_void = (char*)malloc(10);                   //Это некий аналог new ArrayBuffer(x)
memcpy(my_void, &my_string[0], my_string.size());


//std::cout << my_void[2] << std::endl;             //Так естественно нельзя. Это некий аналог :  alert(ArrayBuffer[x])


char* my_char_p = (char*)my_void;                   //Это некий аналог new Uint8Array(ArrayBuffer)

for (int i = 0; i < my_string.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << my_char_p[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Или я ошибаюсь ?

Пользователь Grundy - указывает, что я пишу чушь.

Но, если так, то подскажите в чем именно - она заключатся.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, формально в спецификации не указано, как конкретно должно быть реализовано. Могут быть варианты

Comment: Вы правильно написали, ` Uint8Array(ArrayBuffer)` аналог `char* my_char_p = (char*)my_void;` В JavaScript это представление буфера в нужном виде, в с - изменение (приведение) типа указателя к нужному типу, т.е по сути то же самое.

Comment: @DmitryK, это неверное утверждение

Answer (score 0):

Ну Grundy в целом правильно пишет что ты пишешь чушь.

Обращение `my_buff[2]` столь же бессмысленно как, например, `d = new Date(); alert(d[2])`. Но при этом поскольку и то и другое объекты, то конечно вы можете положить в них любое свойство и потом его прочитать:
`d.answer = 42; alert(d.answer)`.

`ArrayBuffer` не массив. Это специальный объект который используется в `UInt8Array` и т.п. как хранилище байтов. Получить доступ к этим байтам напрямую нельзя.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

UPD: как в очень грубом приближении работает `ArrayBuffer`

```js
my_buff = {
  __hidden_data: [0, ..., 0],
  byteLength: 10,
  // и прочие свойства
};
// и когда вы пишите
my_buff[2] = 42;
// у вас получается примерно такой объект:
my_buff = {
  __hidden_data: [0, ..., 0],
  byteLength: 10,
  '2': 42
}
```

Comment: так не увидел от Вас - в чем чушь то ? Я задал конкретный вопрос с вопросительным знаком. Ответ на него может быть - да или нет, но не увидел от Вам такого ответа.

Comment: Я вообще слово "массив" - ни где не указывал. Может быть Вы все таки "чушь" пишите ?

Comment: Чушь в том что вы пишите `my_buff[2]` и ожидаете что это обращение к одному из тех самых 10 выделенных байтов памяти. Это не так. Те 10 байт через `my_buff` вам вообще никак не доступны, ссылка на них есть в каком-то скрытом свойстве `my_buff` к которому нельзя получить доступ.

Comment: @Staxcelrom добавил как примерно устроен ArrayBuffer

Comment: @Optimus1 перелогинтесь. Хотя может стоит и забанить

Comment: @Staxcelrom ну возможно у меня перепутались в голове с предыдущим вопросом и обсуждением.

Answer (score 0):

Ну почти правильно. Только при выделении памяти размер надо было указать точно.
Если писать на `c`, то без класса `string`

```
// std::string my_string = "Hello_World"; // это - c++
const char* my_string = "Hello_World";
```

`malloc()` выделяет память в байтах. Строка у вас 12 байт (11 символов и завершающий 0). По умолчанию возвращает указатель `void*`, зачем у вас приведение к `char*` а потом приведение опять к `void*` по-умолчанию при операции присваивания?

```
//либо 
char* my_void = (char*)malloc(12); //Это некий аналог new ArrayBuffer(x)
// либо
char* my_void = (char*)malloc( strlen(my_string) + 1 );
```

Раз уж со строками работаете, чтоб не заморачиваться дважды с длиной проще использовать `strcpy()`.  `&my_string[0]` и `my_string` - одно и то же.

```
// memcpy(my_void, &my_string[0], 12);
// memcpy(my_void, my_string, 12);
strcpy( my_void, my_string);
```

Если `my_void` указатель `void*`, то индексировать нельзя, а если `char*`, то можно:

```
std::cout << my_void[2] << std::endl;
```

Ну и дальше вполне рабочий вывод, если у вас размер буфера правильный.
Но можно проще

```
std::cout << my_char_p;
```

Comment: Извините, спорить не буду - не настолько хорошо знаю JavaScript. Убрал из ответа.